# Object.defineProperty called on non-object in my react.js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, defineproperty

I was trying to change a file's name before uploading in my `react.js` application:

Here is the approach :

```
onInputChange = (e) =>{

    let newFileName='dp';
    if(e.target.files.length!==0){
        this.state.file=e.target.files[0];

        Object.defineProperty(this.state.file.name, 'name', {
            writable: true,
            value: newFileName
        });
        console.log(this.state.file);
    }
};
```

But the problem is, whenever this function gets called, I get an error saying :
**Object.defineProperty called on non-object**

How this can be solved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining a new property on a string primitive in the `Object.defineProperty`. The `this.state.file.name` is a string primitive not an object.

```js
const onInputChange = (e) =>{
    
        let newFileName='dp';
        if(e.target.files.length!==0){
            const file = e.target.files[0];
            // file is an object
            // Since file.name is read-only, this is not the proper way to change the name
            // For a file object writable is already true
            Object.defineProperty(file , 'name', {
                value: newFileName
            });
            console.log(file.name);
   
            // Since file name is readonly, and cannot be changed after the File is created
            // This is an alternate way to set the name on a copy of the file object
            const blob = file.slice(0, file.size, file.type); 
            newFile = new File([blob], newFileName, {type: file.type});
            console.log(newFile.name);
       }
};
document.querySelector("#fileInput").addEventListener("change", onInputChange);
```

```html
Upload here:
<input type="file" name="test" id="fileInput"/>
```

Also to update the state do not directly mutate the `this.state` but instead use the `setState()` method to update it.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem. When I edit file name and `console.log` I get the file name as I want. But when I upload it to my server the name remains the old one.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad The `name` is a readonly property , if you set the writable to `true` for file.name it still would not work. try using the alternate method I added in the answer by copying the file object itself using the File constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`this.state.file.name` is a string, not an object, right? Maybe you meant `this.state.file`? And it's not a new property. You're just changing the value. So why not `this.state.file.name = newFileName`?

And as [Maifee points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57996898/object-defineproperty-called-on-non-object-in-my-react-js-application/57996937?noredirect=1#comment102400927_57996968), you may want `file.filename`, not `file.name`.

Comment: I have a problem. When I edit file name and console.log I get the file name as I want. But when I upload it to my server the name remains the old one. You can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY7yf.png)

Comment: I haven't given this a lot of thought but it's possible there's a security restriction that doesn't allow you to change the file name programmatically. You might need to add a field to your form to capture the changed name. Hidden input, [`FormData.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set) or [`FormData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)